# Naked diagrams of human bodies and drawing biological structures

Tags: halal-haram, image, awrah

For many medical/biology classes and for the sake of knowledge, students are asked to learn about the human body, while looking at naked pictures (drawn) for both male and female.

Additionally, students are also asked to draw body parts and cell structure, in order to know and understand how the whole structure is designed.

What's the Islamic position on these 2 issues with regards to the view of tasweer (drawing body parts) and the perspective of viewing drawn awrah?

....all for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: How else would you study medicine?

Comment: I don't understand, what u mean.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the comment mentioned by @Medi1Saif (namely: "How else would you study medicine?" looks profitable; and might be a solver approach.

Secondly, regarding the last part of your question, I'm not certain but think that: it would be permissible in necessary situation -- without Reibeh (the risk of sin ...) or enjoyment ...

Thirdly, in regards to your initial query, I found roughly a similar question-answer, which might help you to some extent, which is as follows: (Based on the Fatwa of Ayatollah Makarem-Shirazi):

Question: What's the Hokm of looking at the unclothes photos in medical books, whose instruction is necessary for the students (of university) and is occasionally with Reibeh (fear of doing haram practice)

**Answer: It is permissible without the intention of enjoyment and Reibeh, and only (can) see in necessary items and in a needed quantity whenever such state is gotten spontaneously.**

---

Source:

https://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/855090/

http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa12710

https://www.porseman.com/article/%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%8A-%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A8%D9%87/169177